# Given a hex for a color, how can I make that color lighter and darker?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, hex

Let's say I have a hex such as: 5fc9f8

Is there a function that accepts "levels of darkness" (-10 to 10) and returns a hex that reflects that?

By darkness I mean add black/remove black from the color.

Comment: Convert it to HSL/HSB and adjust the luminescence/brightness and convert back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit

extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let start = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        return self[start..<(self.index(start, offsetBy: range.count, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex)]
    }
    var hexaCGFloat: CGFloat { .init(strtoul(String(self), nil, 16)) }
}
```

---

```
extension UIColor {
    var rgb: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)? {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        guard getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) else {
            return nil
        }
        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
    var hsb: (hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, brightness: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)? {
        var hue: CGFloat = 0, saturation: CGFloat = 0, brightness: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        guard getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha) else {
            return nil
        }
        return (hue, saturation, brightness, alpha)
    }
    var hsl: (hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, lightness: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)? {
        guard let rgb = rgb, let hsb = hsb else { return nil }
        let maximum = max(rgb.red, rgb.green, rgb.blue)
        let minimum = min(rgb.red, rgb.green, rgb.blue)
        let range = maximum - minimum
        let lightness = (maximum + minimum) / 2.0
        let saturation = range == 0 ? 0 : range / { return lightness < 0.5 ? lightness * 2 : 2 - (lightness * 2) }()
        return (hsb.hue, saturation, lightness, hsb.alpha)
    }
    convenience init(hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, lightness: CGFloat , alpha: CGFloat) {
        var saturation = saturation
        let lightness = lightness * 2
        saturation *= lightness <= 1 ? lightness : 2 - lightness
        self.init(hue: hue,
                  saturation: lightness == 0 ? 0 : (2 * saturation) / (lightness + saturation),
                  brightness: (lightness+saturation)/2,
                  alpha: 1)
    }
    convenience init(hexa: String, alpha: Double) {
        self.init(red:   hexa[0..<2].hexaCGFloat / 255,
                  green: hexa[2..<4].hexaCGFloat / 255,
                  blue:  hexa[4..<6].hexaCGFloat / 255,
                  alpha: .init(alpha))
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing

```
let color = UIColor(hexa: "5fc9f8", alpha: 1)

if let colorHSL = color.hsl {
    let hue = colorHSL.hue
    let saturation = colorHSL.saturation
    let lightness = colorHSL.lightness
    let lighterColor = UIColor(hue: hue,
                               saturation: saturation,
                               lightness: min(lightness * 1.3, 1),
                               alpha: 1)
    let darkerColor = UIColor(hue: hue,
                              saturation: saturation,
                              lightness: max(lightness * 0.5, 0),
                              alpha: 1)
    print("lighterColor:", lighterColor, "darkerColor:", darkerColor)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RGB (Red Green Blue colors, what the hex code represents) is not consistent with color transformations like brightness. The easiest way is to convert the RGB color to HSB (Hue Saturation Brightness) or HSL (Hue Saturation lightness), adjust the brightness or luminescence to the desired brightness, and convert it back to RGB.

See [here](http://www.niwa.nu/2013/05/math-behind-colorspace-conversions-rgb-hsl/) or [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm) for how to convert RGB to HSL.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you set the background color by:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

I'm not going to tell you how to change the brightness by a certain amount, that is up to you, but I'm going to give you exactly what you need to change the brightness of your `backgroundColor` (in this case):

```
//if you want the full brightness... brightness: 1.0
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 1.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
```

This makes the brightness decrease by **50%**, since `brightness: 0.5` not `brightness: 1.0`

but as you can see, it will be easy to tie this to a function to either *increase* or *decrease* the brightness of the `backgroundColor` (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This function will split RGB input value into each component color then add '1' to each (decreasing black, as you put it).  Then it will recombine it to an RGB string and return the value.

Changing the += to -= in a Darken function will "add black".

```
function Lighten(RGB)
{
    var R = parseInt(RGB.substring(0, 2));
    var G = parseInt(RGB.substring(2, 4));
    var B = parseInt(RGB.substring(4, 6));

    R += 1; G += 1; B += 1;

    RGB = R.toString() + G.toString() + B.toString();

    return RGB;
}
```

You could also add a second parameter to take a fixed amount to increase by.